# Does QT use dynamic_cast for QML properties?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I came across curious behavior in QT.

Lets say you have a base controller:

```
class BaseController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    BaseController() = default

protected:
    inline BaseNode * getRoot() const noexcept { return root; }

protected:
    BaseNode * root;
};
```

And ExtraController:

```
class ExtraController final : public BaseController
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY( BaseNode * root READ getRoot NOTIFY changed )

public:
    ExtraController() { root = new ExtraNode(); }

signals:
    void changed();
};
```

Key moment, there is a two type of nodes. **BaseNode** simply an abstract class with property **"id"**. **ExtraNode** is heir of BaseNode and has property **"name".**

Inside qml I use something like:

```
Label {
    text: extraController.root.name // property root - calls getRoot() in BaseController
}
```

And its works! Despite the fact that function getRoot() of a BaseController returns pointer to a BaseNode, which doesn't have "name" property. Question is: **How does it work? How can I use properties of derived class in qml? Does qt perform dynamic_cast or so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt uses [its own meta object system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html). That is why you need MOC and the Q_OBJECT macro.
So Qt "knows" which properties each object has during runtime and uses that knowledge for QML as well.

On the C++ side you can see this through [`QObject::property()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property):

> Returns the value of the object's name property.
> If no such property exists, the returned variant is invalid.
> Information about all available properties is provided through the [metaObject()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#metaObject) and [dynamicPropertyNames()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dynamicPropertyNames).

Note that the properties an object has are independent of its type (see above reference to dynamic properties). The type of an object reference/pointer doesn't matter when accessing the object's properties - the correct meta object and list of properties will always be retrieved.

There is also a [`qobject_cast`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) that makes use of the meta object system to downcast objects.

Comment: I'm aware of MOC system. There is even FINAL keyword in Q_PROPERTY declaration, but in my case i don't have property at all. Its not about override properties or downcast objects. Its QML does some magic i'm trying to understand...

Comment: My answer explains that Qt uses its own meta object system to determine the available properties per-object during runtime. First you fetch the object with `root` accessor. Then QML reads property `name`. At this point the type of the object doesn't matter. You have an object and it has its specific set of properties. Qt will find the property `name` just because it is there.

Comment: Note that accessing properties always runs through method calls. Think of it as a method `getProperty(propertyName)` that is always there for each QObject that you just don't see. The method will always work. It is the same as calling an overridden method on a base pointer (the method call is dispatched during runtime using the vtable).

Comment: I added these details to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sence.